# How to connect different sensors in Raspberry Pi 2 model B?

Tags: raspbian, python

I want to connect Temperature,Moisture and Humidity sensors in Raspberry pi at a time and I have to collect data continuously one after the other.And I don't know how to connect please help me...
I want to use, Temperature sensor=LM35, Humidity and Moisture sensor= DHT22

Comment: a search for your specific sensor and raspberry pi should give you everything you need.

Comment: And BTW: the DHT22 is a temperature/humidity sensor.